# fullscreen matplotlib figures

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am visualising numpy arrays with imshow from pyplot, and would like to see just the array data in a fullscreen display with no toolbars or window borders.

Running with "ipython -pylab" and then calling imshow() and show() gives me a window but pressing "f" does not toggle fullscreen mode. Is there a function call to toggle fullscreen mode? (that would also be preferable to manually pressing a key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think fullscreen is only implemented for the gtk matplotlib backend (I could be very wrong there...).  At any rate, it's definitely not implemented for all platforms and backends that matplotlib supports.

However, from the sounds of what you're doing (simple fullscreen display of a 2D numpy array), you might find [pygarrayimage](http://code.astraw.com/projects/motmot/pygarrayimage.html) useful.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to pygarrayimage - perfect especially since it's already included in EPD